# "Unknown Column" error in Sequelize when using "limit" and "include" options

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have a relatively complex Sequelize query that results in "Error: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'EventImage.EventId' in 'where clause'".  I can clearly see the problem in the SQL that's generated, but I don't know how to resolve it.

The error is accurate as the WHERE clause that's generated in the sub-query is referencing a column not included in the sub-query.  As far as I can tell, Sequelize is generating the sub-query as a way to implement the row limit.

I'm using sequelize@2.0.0-dev11, MySQL 5.5.35-0ubuntu0.13.10.2, and Node v0.10.21.

**Here's the basic code:**

```
var orm = require('../model');
var i = orm.Image;

i.findAll({
    where: where,
    offset: offset,
    limit: rows,
    order: orderby,
    include: [{
        model: orm.User,
        as: 'User'
    },
    {
        model: orm.Event,
        as: 'Events'
    },
    {
        model: orm.Comment,
        as: 'Comments'
    },
    {
        model: orm.Favorite,
        as: 'Favorites'
    }
    ]
})
```

> where = "'Image'.'Category'='gallery' AND 'EventImage'.'EventId' in
>   (1,2)"
>  offset = 0
>  rows = 12
>  orderby = "Image.createdAt
>   DESC"

Sequelize is initialized with the following options:

> underscored: false,
>  freezeTableName: true,
>  paranoid: true,
>   syncOnAssociation: true,
>  charset: 'utf8',
>  collate:
>   'utf8_general_ci',
>  timestamps: true

**Here's the SQL that gets generated:**

```
SELECT 
    `Image` . *,
    `User`.`id` AS `User.id`,
    `User`.`LoginName` AS `User.LoginName`,
    `User`.`FirstName` AS `User.FirstName`,
    `User`.`LastName` AS `User.LastName`,
    `User`.`EmailAddress` AS `User.EmailAddress`,
    `User`.`ProfileImage` AS `User.ProfileImage`,
    `User`.`Password` AS `User.Password`,
    `User`.`Enabled` AS `User.Enabled`,
    `User`.`Expiry` AS `User.Expiry`,
    `User`.`createdAt` AS `User.createdAt`,
    `User`.`updatedAt` AS `User.updatedAt`,
    `User`.`deletedAt` AS `User.deletedAt`,
    `Events`.`id` AS `Events.id`,
    `Events`.`StartDate` AS `Events.StartDate`,
    `Events`.`EndDate` AS `Events.EndDate`,
    `Events`.`Title` AS `Events.Title`,
    `Events`.`Description` AS `Events.Description`,
    `Events`.`createdAt` AS `Events.createdAt`,
    `Events`.`updatedAt` AS `Events.updatedAt`,
    `Events`.`deletedAt` AS `Events.deletedAt`,
    `Events`.`UserId` AS `Events.UserId`,
    `Events`.`ImageId` AS `Events.ImageId`,
    `Events.EventImage`.`createdAt` AS `Events.EventImage.createdAt`,
    `Events.EventImage`.`updatedAt` AS `Events.EventImage.updatedAt`,
    `Events.EventImage`.`ImageId` AS `Events.EventImage.ImageId`,
    `Events.EventImage`.`EventId` AS `Events.EventImage.EventId`,
    `Comments`.`id` AS `Comments.id`,
    `Comments`.`Body` AS `Comments.Body`,
    `Comments`.`createdAt` AS `Comments.createdAt`,
    `Comments`.`updatedAt` AS `Comments.updatedAt`,
    `Comments`.`deletedAt` AS `Comments.deletedAt`,
    `Comments`.`UserId` AS `Comments.UserId`,
    `Comments`.`ImageId` AS `Comments.ImageId`,
    `Comments`.`EventId` AS `Comments.EventId`,
    `Favorites`.`id` AS `Favorites.id`,
    `Favorites`.`createdAt` AS `Favorites.createdAt`,
    `Favorites`.`updatedAt` AS `Favorites.updatedAt`,
    `Favorites`.`UserId` AS `Favorites.UserId`,
    `Favorites`.`ImageId` AS `Favorites.ImageId`
FROM
    (SELECT 
        `Image` . *
    FROM
        `Image` AS `Image`
    WHERE
        `Image`.`Category` = 'gallery'
            AND `EventImage`.`EventId` in (2)
            AND `Image`.`deletedAt` IS NULL
    LIMIT 12) AS `Image`
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
    `User` AS `User` ON `User`.`id` = `Image`.`UserId`
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
    `EventImage` AS `Events.EventImage` ON `Image`.`id` = `Events.EventImage`.`ImageId`
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
    `Event` AS `Events` ON `Events`.`id` = `Events.EventImage`.`EventId`
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
    `Comment` AS `Comments` ON `Image`.`id` = `Comments`.`ImageId`
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
    `Favorite` AS `Favorites` ON `Image`.`id` = `Favorites`.`ImageId`
ORDER BY Image.createdAt DESC;
```

**Here's an EER diagram of the relevant tables:**
[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: did you try  `where = "'Image'.'Category'='gallery' AND 'Events.EventImage'.'EventId' in (1,2)"`

Comment: @Sampat Basically the same error:  "Unknown column 'Events.EventImage.EventId' in 'where clause'"

Comment: why do you need EventImage table if you are storing ImageId in Event table?

Comment: @Sampat The ImageID in the Event table is specific to that Event, like a book cover.  The EventImage table relate other images to Events, like pages in that book.

Comment: any solution? i'm facing same issue here

Comment: @krolow I never got an answer to this exactly.  I ended up using a raw SQL query instead.  Not the solution I wanted, but it got me past the problem.

Comment: I'm facing the exact same. Using findAll works but as soon as I add in limit, it breaks.

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue when adding limit.

Answer (score 14):

I'm not sure if it still needs it, but for those who's suffering, try adding
`subQuery: false` to the query. [Source.](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/9869#issuecomment-469823359)

If it won't work, try adding `separate: true` to the subqueries. [Source.](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/9869#issuecomment-510393362)

Hope it helps, gl.

Comment: Thank you so much. This answer needs to be highlighted!

Answer (score 1):

when a model is included with an alias and its inside an another model also included then the issue arises because of inside model which does not support the given alias given for the parent included model, so the solution is to use the subquery = false for model on which you want to set order and the inner model then does not call for that purpose.

```
include: [
                {
                    model: TeacherDetail.scope('teacherListing'),
                    where: {
                    },
                    subQuery: false,

                    include: [
                        {
                            model: Education,
                            attributes: [],
                        }
                    ]
                },
]
```