# Sequelize throws generic error messages when querying the database

Tags: postgresql, express, sequelize.js

```
Sequelize version: 6.13.0
Database version: PostgreSQL 13.3
```

Whenever there's an issue with a query, Sequelize doesn't tell me the actual issue. For example, [this old Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23312868/2430657) shows Sequelize displaying an error that a column is unknown. In my case, I receive a generic error message and need to manually inspect the queries and my database tables to find out what's wrong. Here's an example:

```
const user = await User.findByPk(params.id);

const settings = await Setting.findAll({ attributes: ['id', 'key', 'defaultValue'] });
const userSettings = await user.getUserSettings({ attributes: ['id', 'key', 'value'] });
```

This will produce the following SQL:

```
Executing (default): SELECT "id", "name", "email", "password", "referralCode", "referredByUserId", "bio", "twitterUrl", "facebookUrl", "instagramUrl", "createdAt", "updatedAt" FROM "Users" AS "User" WHERE "User"."id" = '1';
Executing (default): SELECT "id", "key", "defaultValue" FROM "Settings" AS "Setting";
Executing (default): SELECT "id", "key", "value" FROM "UserSettings" AS "UserSetting" WHERE "UserSetting"."userId" = 1;
```

And here's the error message:

```
/home/user/app/backend/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/query.js:76
    const errForStack = new Error();
                        ^
Error: 
    at Query.run (/home/user/app/backend/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/query.js:76:25)
    at /home/user/app/backend/node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js:642:28
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at PostgresQueryInterface.select (/home/user/app/backend/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/query-interface.js:979:12)
    at Function.findAll (/home/user/app/backend/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:1789:21)
    at HasMany.get (/home/user/app/backend/node_modules/sequelize/lib/associations/has-many.js:228:21)
```

I had to manually check my database tables, and I found out that the `key` column is not present on the UserSettings table.

Why doesn't Sequelize tell me this on any of my models? Is there some configuration I'm missing?

Comment: You can use additional props in Sequelzie error to output the error with more details

Comment: @Anatoly Thank you for your response. Where in the documentation can I find that?

Comment: You can look here https://sequelize.org/master/identifiers.html#errors

Comment: @Anatoly Thank you. This does not solve my issue unfortunately. The issue is that Sequelize, the package, is throwing a generic error message. I am not raising the exception so I don't have the option to configure it. I am wondering why Sequelize itself is not telling me the specific error message when it is working for others.

Comment: Did you catch the error and look at the error object?

Comment: Hi @Anatoly, I just did, and it is showing the error! I had expected it to show the error message in my server's console output. I come from a Ruby on Rails background, so that's why I had such an expectation. I'll use ideas from [this issue](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/1707) to create a centralized way of surfacing these errors specific to my application. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

As @Anatoly mentioned in the comments, I just needed to catch the errors in try-catch block, like this for example:

```
try {
  const user = await User.findByPk(params.id);

  const settings = await Setting.findAll({ attributes: ['id', 'key', 'defaultValue'] });
  const userSettings = await user.getUserSettings({ attributes: ['id', 'key', 'value'] });
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e);
  next(e);
}
```

Coming from a Ruby on Rails background, I had expected the errors to be shown in the output of my terminal running the Express server, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Thanks @Anatoly, debugging will be a lot easier now!